# Get accordion with cookies to remember the link states too

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies, accordion

I used the code from here http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-vertical-accordion-menu-with-cookies/ and modified it a bit to fit my project and it's working really well. Now i have two obstacles that i can't seem to get over.

1: Is it possible that the cookie also stores the state of the last link i clicked? Like giving it a class so i can apply another background colour with css? It would have to remove the class again, if I click a link in one of the child uls i guess so only one link is active at a time.

2: when I refresh the page by clicking the logo above the accordion it stays open. I would love to have it all collapsed again, like when I first visit the site.

Tricky stuff. I have a working demo [here](http://hrvst.net/accordion/cookie.html) (could'nt get it to work on jsfiddle)

This is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
  if (checkCookie != "") {
    $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active').next().show();
  }
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
      var navIndex = $('#nav > li > a').index(this);
      $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
       if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){
           $(this).next().slideUp();
       } else {
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
       }
       $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it's already doing that. That's why the active links are darker. Look within the  tags for this line and change the values for different colors:

```
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {background: #999; color: #fff;}
```

If you want each one to have different colors when active, that's possible too, but you would then want to give them unique ids (similar to class, but typically unique per element) and modify their properties using CSS selectors.

For your second question, try removing this line:

```
if (checkCookie != "") {
    $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active').next().show();
    }
```

Because that's where it's checking the stored value of the cookie after page load. It's not saving the cookies for me locally so I couldn't verify that worked. You may want to clear the `nav-item` cookie on page load.

Comment: Ah okay, didn't see that it already remembers the state of the links in the mein menu. But it doesn't in the submenu. It also needs to remove the class in the main menu and attach it to the submenu once a link in the submenu is clicked. <br><br> Deleting that line in the JS resets the accordion, right. but it also makes it loose the ability to "remember" its state, which is a feature i definitly need to keep!